# Disable accent functionality from backtick button

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

I often type backticks (`) in various situations (Markdown, Github, SO, etc), and since the button used to type them also is used to modify letters (é/è/ú), writing backticks is generally a pain. On a scandinavian keyboard you also have to add the `shift` modifier, which doesn't help.

Currently, I feel like `shift`+`backtick`+`space` is the most predictable way of typing backticks.

But! I realized that I *never* use that key for anything other than backticks, and figured that it would be neat to modify the key to simply always output a single backtick. I can totally live with losing the accent functionality, but I guess it could potentially be kept accessible through modifiers.

I looked into Karabiner to achieve this, and while it's possible to rebind the key, it doesn't seem possible to map its output to a single backtick character.

And ideas?

Comment: Exactly which keyboard are you talking about?  That should be in the title, since the standard US layout does not use this for accents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy to make a custom layout which removes the dead key function from a key using [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele).

Comment: That link does not seem to work.

Comment: Hi, I've installed Ukelele and it's not immediately obvious what to do. Please expand your answer to contain instructions of how to disable accent functionality from the backtick key.

Comment: @byxor Go to the Ukelele > Help menu and get the manual.  Tell me exactly what keyboard layout you are using and I can do this in a minute or two,

Comment: @TomGewecke No worries, the problem is solved. I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46202010/5601284) on a slightly different StackOverflow question. I also saw your name a few times while reading through an Apple [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7706681) haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can also press `shift`+`option`+`backtick` to insert the plain backtick without the accent prompt.